# How to make 1-dimensional plot, where values are represented by colors, not on y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to generate a plot in matplotlib, which would show what kind of mixing type is dominant in different section of a star (1-dimensional section). Data is loaded from file, and mixing types are represented by integers (from 1 to 6). I would like to show it, not on standard 2-dimensional plot, but as a colorbar, where values of parameter are shown not as y value, but as colors on x-axis.

Comment: Where is the code? When posting a question, always show the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to creates such plots. Depending on how many plots and how many x values you want to show you might prefer a different approach. If there is a clear hierarchy in the values, this can be reflected in the colors chosen.

Here is an example using `imshow()` to get you started.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(1, 7, 25)
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('inferno', 6)
plt.imshow(x.reshape(1, -1), cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=6)
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.text(i, 0, x[i], ha='center', va='center', color='navy' if x[i] >= 5 else 'white')
plt.xticks(range(len(x)))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]